# Pausing SKSpriteNode (Swift, SpriteKite)

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

I need to pause the balls for my game. I want them to stop in place but they are moving by impulse and if I make them non-dynamic to stop them, the impulse goes away. I'm trying to pause them and un-pause them, and they still keep going in the same direction. I tried

```
      ball.paused = true
```

but that didn't work. Anyone know?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of freezing the nodes, I froze the scene with
          scene?.physicsWorld.speed = 0
because that freezes all of the nodes and not my time or score integers which is exactly what I needed.

Answer (score 1):

Here is how I solved it in my game:

```
var ballVelocity  = CGVector()

func pauseAction(ball: SKSpriteNode){

    if ball.dynamic {
        //Ball is moving. Save the current velocity of ball.
        ballVelocity = ball.velocity
        //Stop the ball
        ball.physicsBody.dynamic = false

    }else{
        //Ball is paused.
        //Resume ball movement.
        ball.physicsBody.dynamic = true
        //Add the saved velocity.
        ball.velocity = ballVelocity
    }  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ball.physicsBody.velocity = CGVectorMake(0, 0);` but keep in mind that if the ball is affected by gravity, it will still drop.

Comment: Yeah I tried that after I posted the question. That doesnt work because it doesnt put the balls back into motion. It just freezes them and when its time for them to be unfrozen they dont move.

Comment: @drewvy22 - When you "unfreeze" just apply an impulse to it again.

Comment: that doesnt work because this is being put in the override func update function so the force just keeps being applied. And it has to be in that specific function in order for everything else to work. I just dont understand why the ball.pause = true doesnt work at all